# What algorithm to reassemble a broken image?

Tags: image

What algorithm can I use to reassemble a broken image?
[image]

Is there any technique? algorithm? Can I use graphs? machine learning? computer graphics?

Comment: Are rotations also involved? Further, is it like a jigsaw puzzle or can there also be overlap (e.g. image stitching for panoramas)?

Comment: @SimonF 
If we assume each part as a vertex, I need to know the adjacencies of each vertex

Answer (score 3):

If the pieces are fairly close to where they were, [ICP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) could be of help (under the assumption that the pieces are planar polygons).

Comment: thanks 
I would be interested in obtaining the adjacencies in text, the graphic part is not so impresindible

Comment: your answer is good that interesting the graphic part